# Java multidimensional Array shown in OptionPane

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, joptionpane

I can't find a way how to get to get a JOptionPane show the multidimensional array.

This is my first attempt.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int[][] numbers = new int[5][5];

    int rows = 5;
    int columns = 5;

    numbers[0][0] = 30;
    numbers[0][1] = 29;
    numbers[0][2] = 28;
    numbers[0][3] = 27;
    numbers[0][4] = 26;

    numbers[1][0] = 26;
    numbers[1][2] = 25;
    numbers[1][2] = 24;
    numbers[1][3] = 23;
    numbers[1][4] = 22;

    int x, y;

    for (x = 0;  x < rows; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < columns; y++)
        {
            System.out.print(numbers[x][y] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numbers,"Arrays",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

This is the JOptionPane output

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfyjsgeaimpr2dh/JOptionPane%20output.PNG

As you can see something is wrong.

The console output is looks like this.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ac0a65kttdora27/Console%20output.PNG

And what I want is that you see the console output is shown in the JOptionPane.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) in the same way you are printing to the console :

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int[][] numbers = new int[5][5];

    int rows = 5;
    int columns = 5;

    numbers[0][0] = 30;
    numbers[0][1] = 29;
    numbers[0][2] = 28;
    numbers[0][3] = 27;
    numbers[0][4] = 26;

    numbers[1][0] = 26;
    numbers[1][2] = 25;
    numbers[1][2] = 24;
    numbers[1][3] = 23;
    numbers[1][4] = 22;

    int x, y;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (x = 0;  x < rows; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < columns; y++)
        {
            builder.append(numbers[x][y] + " ");
        }
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, builder,"Arrays",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply pass the `numbers` array to the `showMessageDialog()` and expect it to know how you want it to be displayed. You have to look for a suitable layout by yourself. Perhaps you create a `JPanel` and layout some `JLabels` on it to display your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

OK You can proceed as follows:

```
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
sBuilder.append("<Html><Body>");
sBuilder.append("<Table>");
for (int i = 0  ; i < numbers.length ;i++)
{
  sBuilder.append("<tr>");
  for ( int j = 0 ; j < numbers[i].length; j++)
  {
    sBuilder.append("<td>"+numbers[i][j]+"</td>");
  }
  sBuilder.append("</tr>");
}
sBuilder.append("</Table>");
sBuilder.append("</Body></Html>");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sBuilder.toString(),"Arrays",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```